# How do I show this inequality

Tags: real-analysis

The original question is to show the $f_n(x) = nx \exp(-nx^2)$ converges pointwise and determine the limit function.

I was given the solution, if $x\ne 0$, then 
$|f_n(x)| = \frac{n|x|}{\exp(nx^2)} \le \frac{2n|x|}{(nx^2)^2} = \frac{2}{n|x|^3} \rightarrow 0$
if $x = 0$ then $f_n(0) = 0$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$
Hence $f_n \rightarrow 0$ pointwise
I don't understand why $\frac{n|x|}{\exp(nx^2)} \le \frac{2n|x|}{(nx^2)^2} $

Can someone give me a proof of this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: Use the Taylor series

$$\exp(nx^2) = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(nx^2)^k}{k!} > \frac{(nx^2)^2}{2}$$

Comment: The principle here is the exponential function with positive argument grows faster than any polynomial.